# Is there a way that I can press enter without inputting anything and the code will assume what to do next?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I was tasked to do this:

"Product Code: (press Enter)

if no product code is entered the system simply shows another product code"

So basically I have the option to either input a product code or press enter and another product code will appear and my problem is how to display a product code if the user chooses to press enter rather than inputting a code.

Note that all the product codes are already part of the program and the user just needs to input the product code to change its value.

```
int main(){
int productcode;

    system("CLS");
    cout << "Product Code : ";
    cin >> productcode;
    return 0;}
```

*Update after trying Kanthan's suggestion

I was able to come up with this code:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int d;
    int productcode;
    int p1;
    int d1;
    float v1, gt;
    char ans;
    d1=0;
    gt=v1=0;
    d=26;
    do{
    char code[40];
    system("CLS");
    cout<< "Product code : ";
    cin.getline(code,40,'\n');
    productcode=atoi(code);
    if(code[0]=='\0')
    {
        cout << '\n'<<"Random Product Code appears"<<'\n' << '\n';
        system("PAUSE");
    }

    else if(productcode>410 && productcode<15059){
            switch(productcode){
            case 1001:
                d1=1;
                p1=0;
                cout << '\n' << "Product Code : " << productcode << " - Product - Product Price     Number of Cans: ";
                cin >>  p1;
                if(p1==0){d1=0;v1=0;}   
                break;
            case 15058:
                system("CLS");
                cout << "Items Purchased:" << '\n';
                if(d1==1)
                    {
                        v1=p1*25;

                        cout << "1001 - Product - Product Price x " << p1 << " pc/s = " << v1 << '\n';
                    }
                lines();
                gt=v1;
                cout << "Grand Total : " << gt << " USD" << '\n' << flush;  
                system("PAUSE");
                system("PAUSE");
                break;
            case 8223:
                int mrd;
                mrd=3;
                do{
                    system("CLS");
                cout << "Are you sure that you want to go? Y/N: " << '\n';
                cin >> ans;
                if (ans=='Y'||ans=='y')
                {
                d=27;
                mrd=4;
                cout << '\n' << "Your total sales is " << gt << " USD." << '\n';
                system("PAUSE");
                }
                else if (ans=='N'||ans=='n')
                {
                    mrd=4;
                    cout << '\n' << "Your total sales is at " << gt << " USD." << '\n' << flush;
                    system("PAUSE");
                }
                else
                {
                    system("CLS");
                    cout << "Wrong input. Please try again." << '\n' << flush;
                    system("PAUSE");
                }
                }while(mrd<4);
                break;  
            default:
                system("CLS");
                    cout << "Product Code input is incorrect. Please try again." <<'\n' << flush;
                    system("PAUSE");
                    break;              
                }
        }
    else {
        system("CLS");
                    cout << "Product Code input is incorrect. Please try again." <<'\n' << flush;
                    system("PAUSE");
    }   

    }while(d<27);

}
```

My problem now is that "Random Product Code appears" still shows even if code[0]=='\0' is not true.

Comment: You need to input a whole line using `std::getline`,  and then take action based on whether the line is empty or not.  If not empty then you can convert to int using `stoi` .

Comment: The phrasing with "if" might mislead you. Are you aware of the concept of loops?

Comment: @M.M , May I know a code example how the program can detect if the line is empty or not?

Comment: @Bobby use the `empty()` member function of `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


int myisdigit(const char *str);

int main()
{
    char str[40];
    int code;

    std::cout<<"Enter Product code:";
    std::cin.getline(str,40,'\n');

    if(str[0]=='\0')
    {
        std::cout<<"Next Product";
    }
    else
    {
        if(!myisdigit(str))
        {
            std::cout<<"Enter Proper Code";
            exit(1);
        }
        code=atoi(str);
        std::cout<<"Product Number:"<<code;
    }
}

int myisdigit(const char *str)
{

    while(*str)
    {
        if( ! ( ( ( *str ) >= '0' ) && ( (*str) <='9' ) ) )
            return 0;

        str++;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Or if you want to use `std::string` make some changes in the code like

```
    std::string mystr;
    int code;
    const char *str;

    std::cout<<"Enter Product code:";
    std::getline(std::cin,mystr);

    str=mystr.c_str();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I encountered a new problem. Please check the updated status.

Comment: @Bobby         please give some info about how did you give the input